# Office add-in SSO feature not returning access_as_user scope for guest users

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office-js

I am developing an Office.js based (non-VSTO) Word add-in and I'm using the SSO feature [outlined here](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/create-sso-office-add-ins-aspnet) for authentication.

I'm having an issue in certain cases with the token returned by the Office.js method `Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync()`

As I understand it, this method is meant to return an Access Token from Office which can then be exchanged for a Microsoft Graph API token. In order for this exchange to work though, the Office token must contain the value `access_as_user` in its `scp` claim.

**The working case**

For normal users in my Azure Active Directory, the Office token includes the `access_as_user` scope in the claims and I am able to successfully exchange that token for a Graph token.

**The broken case**

For guest (aka B2B) users in my Azure Active Directory, the `scp` claim on the Office token is empty and I am unable to exchange that token for a Graph token.

I have opened issues with Microsoft and communicated to some extent with their developers around the issue. From that, it sounds like the missing scope for guest users may be a bug in the feature. Can anyone confirm whether this feature is intended to work with guest users or offer suggestions for getting this working in that case?

Comment: I'm curious about this scenario. The SSO mechanism works by getting you a token for the current Word user but a "Guest" would seem to not have a license for Word in the tenant?

Comment: Correct, the guest user does not have a license in "my" tenant but they will have a license in their own tenant that they are not a guest user in. I am able to successfully log in as the guest user in desktop Word.

Comment: SSO in this context is about getting a token for the user logged into Word. Since a guest user can't be licensed for Word, they can't login using the guest credentials. If you want them to log into your tenant, they'll need to authenticate rather than use SSO.

Comment: But I can add a user who is licensed for Word in another tenancy as a guest user in my tenancy, right? In that case the guest user is licensed for Word but that case still seems not to work.

Comment: They can be a guest in your tenant but SSO will always authenticate them in their tenant. While they may have access tenants, they're two distinct user records and the token returned is for _their_ tenant. In order to use your tenant you will need to have them authenticate.